# HTML href link with question mark

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I've got problem with a href link and quote mark

i should to generate link like this

```
<a class="vk_share__a" href = "http://vk.com/share.php?url=http://vita-plant.ru<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"] ?>&title=<?=$arResult[NAME]?>&description=<?=$arResult[PREVIEW_TEXT]?>&image=http://vita-plant.ru<?=$social_img_link;?>" id="vk_share_button<?=$social_id?>"></a>
```

when i check and click it in chrome developer tools it's work correct, with cyrillyc letter

```
<a href="http://vk.com/share.php?url=Привет мир" title="">клик</a>
```

but when i hover and click it on page a get something like this

```
http://vk.com/share.php?url=%CF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2%20%EC%E8%F0
```

when i need

```
http://vk.com/share.php?url=Привет%20мир
```

[image]

how can i get cyryllic letter in chrome developer tools and in hover-click event?

Mb it's php mod_rewrite or htaccess?

thank you!

Comment: I suggest you read about unicodes: joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

This is actually working correctly.

URLs cannot contain non-ASCII characters, so the Cyrillic is being converted to [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) by the browser to ensure it correct.